# Enterprise Architect: DB schema update from odbc oracle drivers - synchronization not working

Tags: oracle, import, odbc, enterprise-architect

When I try update one selected table using import DB schema form ODBC source I get table without links/relationships. I have checked synchronization mode but I get new table with the same name - synchronization not work.

Where is the problem? How can I fix this?

EA 11.1.1112

ODBC Oracle drivers 11.2.0 (11g 32-bits)

Sorry for My English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the table was moved to subfolder in the package. EA not seen moved table to synchronization and create new.

Sorry for My English.